# How to selectively replace function in visual studio in case of function overloading?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have overloaded functions ToString(int), ToString(float),...
I want to replace the calls of only certain functions out of the overloaded functions. Say I want to replace ToString(int) to std::to_string(int) and leave ToString(float) calls as it is. How do it in bulk in visual studio?

Comment: I think you're going to be stuck with plain old find and replace and the mark I human brain filtering out the non-`int` calls.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::string ToString(int x) { return std::to_string(x); }
```

Comment: Nice idea, but I want to remove all calls to ToString(int) altogether.

Comment: I wouldn't dismiss this idea. It's fool-proof and the compiler will optimize it down to non-existent.